# How to install Rasa Stack in Windows 10?

Tags: build, h5py, mpi4py, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Maybe someone else asked the same question too. But this question is difficult. I tried everything. The place I am stuck is with installing dependencies. Some of the dependencies are old and not easily available. But I managed to install them.

The problems lies here.. There are dependencies that need to get the build from their source code. I already installed Visual C++ Build and MSMPI. Also installed HDF5 for H5PY but it doesn't let me build old versions of H5PY. So, I tried installing the latest version of H5PY but still, I am stuck at errors like file not found. Some of the files which the build process cannot find are "h5py/h5f.pyx", "mpi_c", "mpi.h". Solving error for one missing file leads to other and so on..

On trying hard to solve such errors and installing one or the other package to do the same task, I am tired up.. Something I found, at last, was that "mpi_c" file was replaced with some other file in newer versions of MPI4PY. But my dependencies depend on older version. I tried installing an older version of MPI4PY but HDF5 won't let me install that giving other errors. At last, I quit the task with my whole day wasted after this.

So can someone here please provide a step by step guideline for installing Rasa Stack on Windows Machine?

Windows 10 with Python 3.7.. Let me know if I need to downgrade python as well.. It was my first time building some project from source with python on windows. Thanks...

Comment: So you are trying to install Rasa NLU and Core?

Comment: @CalebKeller Yes bro..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps to install Rasa:

1. Install Conda
2. Create a virtual environment:

   conda create -n myenv python=3.5
3. Activate the virtual environment

   conda activate myenv
4. pip install rasa_nlu rasa_core